Grid not resizing to take the width of the items
How can I make each grid box to take the width of the content nested inside? Take the example of the second testimony, the item has a max-width of 500px, but the grid box does not take its width, it just stays the same. What I tried was setting width and max-width for all different testimonies but it doesn't work.
HTML & CSS


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#general-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, auto));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.testimony-one {
  background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
}

#quotation {
  position: absolute;
}

.testimony-five aside {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.testimony-one figure>aside>h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.testimony-one div {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.testimony-one div p,
.testimony-two div p,
.testimony-three div p,
.testimony-four div p,
.testimony-five div p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.testimony-one div h2,
.testimony-two div h2,
.testimony-three div h2,
.testimony-four div h2,
.testimony-five div h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.testimony-one figure>img,
.testimony-two figure>img,
.testimony-three figure>img,
.testimony-four figure>img,
.testimony-five figure>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimony-one figure,
.testimony-two figure,
.testimony-three figure,
.testimony-four figure,
.testimony-five figure {
  display: flex;
}

.testimony-two {
  background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.testimony-two div {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.testimony-two article {
  width: auto;
}

.testimony-two p {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.testimony-two h2 {
  width: 400px;
}

.testimony-three {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.testimony-four {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.testimony-five {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.testimony-five div {
  max-width: 300px;
}
<section id="general-container">
  <article class="testimony-one">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="Daniels testimony" width="80" height="80">
      <aside>
        <h1>Daniel Clifford</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>

      <figure id="quotation">
        <img src="images/bg-pattern-quotation.svg" alt="quotaton marks">
      </figure>
    </figure>
    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so, in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every penny’s worth.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
        The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-two">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-jonathan.jpg" alt="Jonathans testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jonathan Walters</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for a big company. This was one of the best investments I’ve made in myself. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-three">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-jeanette.jpg" alt="Jeanettes testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jeanette Harmon</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        An overall wonderful and rewarding experience
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living while doing something I love. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-four">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-patrick.jpg" alt="Patricks testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Patrick Abrams</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and learning from their experiences was easy.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You
        will get the personal attention you need from an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-five">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-kira.jpg" alt="Kiras testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Kira Whittle</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!
        <p>
          “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about
          the program. The entire curriculum and staff did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that
          no tutorial could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 100% recommend! ”
        </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>



Expected Result


I do not understand the problem. Please edit your post to clarify both your actual results and your desired results. Include some screenshots/sketches if you can.

Hello Brett.
I have tried adding my codes as a whole but without success. Can I create a replit link for you to see my code?

The request is to add a clarification of the actual problem your facing. I think what you mean is that when the window gets too narrow to show the three items next to each other, you want them to be shown below each other? Going from a horizontal row of items to a vertical column of items. Right? I think you need a flexbox for that, not a grid. See: When to use Flexbox and when to use CSS Grid

Grid not resizing: the grid takes 100% of the container width already. It's not clear what you are asking because since you used a grid, that's supposed to have a fixed layout and its rows/cols are expected to take the size you specified in the grid properties.

@DiegoD Yes, the grid already takes 100% of the container width. What I want to achieve now is when I resize one of the testimony cards, the grid section takes the width of the testimony card.
For instance, I expected  testimony-two grid section to be 500px.

Concept
As what you question has described, you want it to be achieved using grid and based on what you have shown in the end result, basically you need grid box that looks like this (a container which has 4 boxes per row):

You may imagine that at the end some contents will occupy spaces of multiple boxes as below:

Based on this concept, then you modify it to be:

Solution (based on your code)
This is what I have modified based on your code (minimal changes, works on full screen):


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

*{
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#general-container{
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem; /* added to get the spacing between boxes */
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, auto));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto); */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */
}

.testimony-one{
  background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.info{
  position: relative;
}

#quotation{
  position: absolute;
}

.testimony-five aside{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.testimony-one figure > aside > h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.testimony-one div {
  /* max-width: 700px; */
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.testimony-one div  p,
.testimony-two div p,
.testimony-three div p,
.testimony-four div p,
.testimony-five div p{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.testimony-one div h2,
.testimony-two div h2,
.testimony-three div h2,
.testimony-four div h2,
.testimony-five div h2{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.testimony-one figure > img,
.testimony-two figure > img,
.testimony-three figure > img,
.testimony-four figure > img,
.testimony-five figure > img{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimony-one figure,
.testimony-two figure,
.testimony-three figure,
.testimony-four figure,
.testimony-five figure{
  display: flex;
}

.testimony-two{
  background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* max-width: 500px; */
}

.testimony-two div{
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.testimony-two article{
  width: auto;
}

.testimony-two p{
  max-width: 400px;
}

.testimony-two h2{
  width: 400px;
}

.testimony-three{
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  border: 1px solid black; /* styling to show the box only */
}

.testimony-four{
  /* grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2; */
  background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.testimony-five{
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* styling to show the box only */
}

/* .testimony-five div{
  max-width: 300px;
} */
<section id="general-container">
  <article class="testimony-one">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="Daniels testimony" width="80" height="80">
      <aside>
        <h1>Daniel Clifford</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>

      <figure id="quotation">
        <img src="images/bg-pattern-quotation.svg" alt="quotaton marks">
      </figure>
    </figure>
    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so, in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every penny’s worth.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
        The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-two">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-jonathan.jpg" alt="Jonathans testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jonathan Walters</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for a big company. This was one of the best investments I’ve made in myself. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-three">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-jeanette.jpg" alt="Jeanettes testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jeanette Harmon</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        An overall wonderful and rewarding experience
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living while doing something I love. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-four">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-patrick.jpg" alt="Patricks testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Patrick Abrams</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and learning from their experiences was easy.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You
        will get the personal attention you need from an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimony-five">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure>
      <img src="images/image-kira.jpg" alt="Kiras testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Kira Whittle</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!
        <p>
          “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about
          the program. The entire curriculum and staff did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that
          no tutorial could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 100% recommend! ”
        </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>



The Way I Would Approach This
Here is how I would do when approach this problem:


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#general-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.testimonial {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.info>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#quotation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 65px;
}

.testimonial:first-child,
.testimonial:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.testimonial:last-child {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.testimonial:first-child {
  background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
}

.testimonial:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
}

.testimonial:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
  color: #fff;
}
<section id="general-container">
  <article class="testimonial">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="Daniels testimony" width="80" height="80">
      <aside>
        <h1>Daniel Clifford</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>

      <figure id="quotation">
        <img src="images/bg-pattern-quotation.svg" alt="quotaton marks">
      </figure>
    </figure>
    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so, in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every penny’s worth.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
        The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimonial">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-jonathan.jpg" alt="Jonathans testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jonathan Walters</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for a big company. This was one of the best investments I’ve made in myself. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimonial">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-jeanette.jpg" alt="Jeanettes testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Jeanette Harmon</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        An overall wonderful and rewarding experience
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living while doing something I love. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimonial">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-patrick.jpg" alt="Patricks testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Patrick Abrams</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and learning from their experiences was easy.
      </h2>
      <p>
        “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You
        will get the personal attention you need from an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="testimonial">
    <!--reviewer Image and name info-->
    <figure class="info">
      <img src="images/image-kira.jpg" alt="Kiras testimony">
      <aside>
        <h1>Kira Whittle</h1>
        <h1>Verified Graduate</h1>
      </aside>
    </figure>

    <!--Review-->
    <div>
      <h2>
        Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!
        <p>
          “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about
          the program. The entire curriculum and staff did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that
          no tutorial could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 100% recommend! ”
        </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>



What I have modified
In the html, I have changed all testimonies, i.e. testimony-one, testimony-two, etc. to only testimonial (Btw, it should be testimonial rather than testimony - see here). Besides, I added info class for all figure so that the same CSS can be applied to all images.
In the CSS, I use :first-child, :last-child, :nth-child() to refer to different testimonials in order to make the CSS more manageable.
Key Concepts
In this solution, I use span in grid-column in the child boxes to make the item occupies multiple boxes. For e.g., grid-column: span 3; means that the item will take 3 grid-boxes across 3 columns (horizontally). It works for grid-row too. grid-row: span 3; will occupy 3 boxes vertically. However, this will not work in your case since you are using the last testimonial; if you are using the 3rd testimonial and expand it vertically, it will work.
Besides, grid-row: 1 / 3; is the shorthand for grid-row-start: 1; grid-row-end: 3; which is the same as what I saw you tried out in your code.
Furthermore, you can use grid-template-areas to achieve the same result. I add an example for your reference:
#general-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "testimonial1 testimonial1 testmonial2 testimonial5"
        "testimonial3 testimonial4 testmonial4 testimonial5";
}

.testimonial:first-child {
    grid-area: testimonial1;
}

.testimonial:last-child {
    grid-area: testimonial5;
}

Things That Are Not Covered Here
Since my main focus is to help you aligning all the testimonial boxes correctly, many of the other areas are not covered here, for. e.g.:

Container max-width and align it at the center.
Styles to make the overall looks nicer (font, margin, padding, etc.).
Container / Media Queries for responsive layout.


Please let me know if this helps or you need further assistance.

It's not working, it's affecting my other testimony cards. I wish I could post my whole code so that you see the behaviour. Can I create a replit for this?

Are you asking something like each box not same width?

I have edited the post for clarity. I'm clear enough now.

Could you edit and attach an image of the end result you wish to achieve? I think you need to use flexbox instead of sticking to grid. If you're okay with it, I edit my answer to help you.

I think your question background and the code you tried are good enough to tell the story, just need an image as the expected result.

Btw, just to clarify, I didn't vote to close your question, I was surprised too when I saw that, all the while I was just waiting your reply to help you further.

@StephenMutheu please let me know if you need any help.

I'm yet to solve my problem. Let me create a code pen with my entire code so that you see how the grid behaves.

Here is the link.
https://codepen.io/Stephen-Mutheu/pen/zYQRRvE
Notice how the second testimony leaves some space to the right. I do not want that.

Okay, what do you expecting? Can you draw it out in Paint, Word, Excel? Or even hand drawing? The code you have put in your question since then, I can see that... You kept sending us your code in different ways, ya, I can see that, thanks for your effort, but what I'm asking is, what do you expect to see as end result?

Ok. I have edited the original post and included a link that will re-direct to the end product. I have really tried to be clear, I don't know how to express the problem if this don't help you, I have done my best. I wish I'd receive some support on how the forum works, it's hard working my way out without support.

@StephenMutheu please let me know if you need further help.

This was helpful bro, I can't believe I ignored the grid areas method, lol! Thanks, man!

Nice, glade to hear that! Could you accept the answer then? Later I may help you to edit the question to reopen it, now too many pending edits...

Can you show me how to accept it?

Beside my answer, there is an upvote downvote, below there got a tick, tick there, here is a guide for it

Done. Thanks for your patience and support.
